# JOOQ dynamic set

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I would like to update only fields that had been updated (they wont be null).
I would like to create a dynamic set, for example (not a valid code):

```
dslContext.update(table)
            if(field1 != null) {
              .set(field1, val1)
            }
            if(field2 != null) {
              .set(field2, val2)
            }
            .where(condition1)
            .and(condition2)
            .execute();
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

While you could certainly achieve this by (ab)using the DSL API, the best way to actually do this is by using one of the following methods:

- [`UpdateSetStep.set(Map)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdateSetStep.html#set-java.util.Map-)
- [`UpdateSetStep.set(Record)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdateSetStep.html#set-org.jooq.Record-)

An example using `Record`:

```java
Record record = dslContext.newRecord(table);

if (field1 != null)
    record.set(field1, val1)

if (field2 != null) {
    record.set(field2, val2)

dslContext.update(table)
          .set(record)
          .where(condition1)
          .and(condition2)
          .execute();
```